# Aba TimeLine no Chrome, não tem

Tags: google-chrome

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?hl=pt-br

Meu Chrome 61.0.3163.91 64 bits já revirei e não encontro de forma alguma esta aba[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi corretamente a sua pergunta mas você se referia a esse botão:?

> **Show overview** na aba **Network**

[image: Show overview na aba Network]

Comment: parece mas acho que não é a mesma coisa, como o link da pagina de ajuda do Chrome que postei na aba Timeline tem mais informações para analisar as funções js que são executadas por exemplo